# Entity Framework query fails after 23 subqueries, need to add more

Tags: c#, entity-framework, t-sql, gridview

I have an Entity Framework query I was using to output 31 columns from two tables to a gridview. 29 columns are bits so they appear as True or False. Trying to update this to show Yes or No instead, I added a subquery to each bit column to select a Yes or No or NULL from a lookup table where the bit value is 1 or 0 or NULL. This works for about 23 columns, after that the query returns no results and the gridview does not load. I can return the remaining columns as bits and show True or False, but as soon as i change any of them to use the subquery, the query fails and the gridview does not load. I thought the issue could be command timeout or connection time out. i added this for command time out

```
db.Database.CommandTimeout = 3000; db.Configuration.AutoDetectChangesEnabled = false;
```

I added the following in `web.config`:

```
Connection Timeout=6000
```

Still nothing works. could this be a memory or cache issue? here is the query

```
using (var db = new EthicsEntities())
{
    db.Database.CommandTimeout = 3000;
    //db.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = true;
    db.Configuration.AutoDetectChangesEnabled = false;

    string sstartyear = Convert.ToString(startyear);
    string eendyear = Convert.ToString(endyear);
    var questrpt = (from f in db.FDS
                    join q in db.Questions
                    on f.FDS_Num equals q.FDS_Num
                    where f.Filed_Year >= startyear
                    && f.Filed_Year <= endyear
                    orderby f.Filed_Year, f.FDS_Num          

                    select new 
                    {
                        fdsnum = q.FDS_Num,
                        yearr = f.Filed_Year,
                        //rQ01 = q.Q1,
                        rQ01 = (from y in db.YesNoes where y.YN_Bit == q.Q1 select y.YN_Value).FirstOrDefault(),
                        //rQ02 = q.Q2,
                        rQ02 = (from y in db.YesNoes where y.YN_Bit == q.Q2 select y.YN_Value).FirstOrDefault(),
                        //rQ03 = q.Q3,
                        rQ03 = (from y in db.YesNoes where y.YN_Bit == q.Q3 select y.YN_Value).FirstOrDefault(),
                        //rQ04 = q.Q4,
                        rQ04 = (from y in db.YesNoes where y.YN_Bit == q.Q4 select y.YN_Value).FirstOrDefault(),
                        //rQ05 = q.Q5,
                        rQ05 = (from y in db.YesNoes where y.YN_Bit == q.Q5 select y.YN_Value).FirstOrDefault(),
                        //rQ06 = q.Q6,
                        rQ06 = (from y in db.YesNoes where y.YN_Bit == q.Q6 select y.YN_Value).FirstOrDefault(),
                        //rQ07 = q.Q7,
                        rQ07 = (from y in db.YesNoes where y.YN_Bit == q.Q7 select y.YN_Value).FirstOrDefault(),
                        //rQ08 = q.Q8,
                        rQ08 = (from y in db.YesNoes where y.YN_Bit == q.Q8 select y.YN_Value).FirstOrDefault(),
                        //rQ09 = q.Q9,
                        rQ09 = (from y in db.YesNoes where y.YN_Bit == q.Q9 select y.YN_Value).FirstOrDefault(),
                        //rQ10 = q.Q10,
                        rQ10 = (from y in db.YesNoes where y.YN_Bit == q.Q10 select y.YN_Value).FirstOrDefault(),
                        //rQ11 = q.Q11,
                        rQ11 = (from y in db.YesNoes where y.YN_Bit == q.Q11 select y.YN_Value).FirstOrDefault(),
                        //rQ12 = q.Q12,
                        rQ12 = (from y in db.YesNoes where y.YN_Bit == q.Q12 select y.YN_Value).FirstOrDefault(),
                        //rQ13 = q.Q13,
                        rQ13 = (from y in db.YesNoes where y.YN_Bit == q.Q13 select y.YN_Value).FirstOrDefault(),
                        //rQ14 = q.Q14,
                        rQ14 = (from y in db.YesNoes where y.YN_Bit == q.Q14 select y.YN_Value).FirstOrDefault(),
                        //rQ15 = q.Q15,
                        rQ15 = (from y in db.YesNoes where y.YN_Bit == q.Q15 select y.YN_Value).FirstOrDefault(),
                        //rQ16 = q.Q16,
                        rQ16 = (from y in db.YesNoes where y.YN_Bit == q.Q16 select y.YN_Value).FirstOrDefault(),
                        //rQ17 = q.Q17,
                        rQ17 = (from y in db.YesNoes where y.YN_Bit == q.Q17 select y.YN_Value).FirstOrDefault(),
                         //rQ18 = q.Q18,
                         rQ18 = (from y in db.YesNoes where y.YN_Bit == q.Q18 select y.YN_Value).FirstOrDefault(),
                         //rQ19 = q.Q19,
                         rQ19 = (from y in db.YesNoes where y.YN_Bit == q.Q19 select y.YN_Value).FirstOrDefault(),
                         //rQ20 = q.Q20,
                         rQ20 = (from y in db.YesNoes where y.YN_Bit == q.Q20 select y.YN_Value).FirstOrDefault(),
                         rQ21 = q.Q21,
                         //rQ21 = (from y in db.YesNoes where y.YN_Bit == q.Q21 select y.YN_Value).FirstOrDefault(),
                         rQ22 = q.Q22,
                         //rQ22 = (from y in db.YesNoes where y.YN_Bit == q.Q22 select y.YN_Value).FirstOrDefault(),
                         rQ23 = q.Q23,
                         //rQ23 = (from y in db.YesNoes where y.YN_Bit == q.Q23 select y.YN_Value).FirstOrDefault(),
                         rQ24 = q.Q24,
                         //rQ24 = (from y in db.YesNoes where y.YN_Bit == q.Q24 select y.YN_Value).FirstOrDefault(),
                         rQ25 = q.Q25,
                         //rQ25 = (from y in db.YesNoes where y.YN_Bit == q.Q25 select y.YN_Value).FirstOrDefault(),
                         rQ26 = q.Q26,
                         //rQ26 = (from y in db.YesNoes where y.YN_Bit == q.Q26 select y.YN_Value).FirstOrDefault(),
                         //rQ27 = q.Q27,
                         rQ27 = (from y in db.YesNoes where y.YN_Bit == q.Q27 select y.YN_Value).FirstOrDefault(),
                         //rQ28 = q.Q28,
                         rQ28 = (from y in db.YesNoes where y.YN_Bit == q.Q28 select y.YN_Value).FirstOrDefault(),
                         //rQ29 = q.Q29
                         rQ29 = (from y in db.YesNoes where y.YN_Bit == q.Q29 select y.YN_Value).FirstOrDefault()
                     }).ToList();

    grdQuestions.DataSource = questrpt;
    grdQuestions.DataBind();
    grdQuestions.HeaderRow.TableSection = TableRowSection.TableHeader;
}
```

Comment: Did you ever stop to think maybe this isnt a great approach?

Comment: Yes, I created a method to accept bool? and return string "Yes" or "No" but it didnt work inside the entity query. Can you advise a better approach to converting the true/ false to yes/ no?

Comment: *the query fails* -- How does it fail? Do you see any exception messages?

Comment: there is no exception, maybe i phrased that wrong. the grid view doesn't load if i add one more subquery. if i don't use subqueries, the grid view loads and shows True/False. i want to use the subqueries to display Yes/No. logically i can't figure out why i am limited to the number of subqueries where the grid view does not load. i appreciate any insight! thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the solution that worked for me. Thanks All! Any questions, feel free to ask!

```
                                    rQ01 = (q.Q1 == true) ? "Yes" : "No",
                                    rQ02 = (q.Q2 == true) ? "Yes" : "No",
                                    rQ03 = (q.Q3 == true) ? "Yes" : "No",
                                    rQ04 = (q.Q4 == true) ? "Yes" : "No",
                                    rQ05 = (q.Q5 == true) ? "Yes" : "No",
                                    rQ06 = (q.Q6 == true) ? "Yes" : "No",
                                    rQ07 = (q.Q7 == true) ? "Yes" : "No",
                                    rQ08 = (q.Q8 == true) ? "Yes" : "No",
                                    rQ09 = (q.Q9 == true) ? "Yes" : "No",
                                    rQ10 = (q.Q10 == true) ? "Yes" : "No",
                                    rQ11 = (q.Q11 == true) ? "Yes" : "No",
                                    rQ12 = (q.Q12 == true) ? "Yes" : "No",
                                    rQ13 = (q.Q13 == true) ? "Yes" : "No",
                                    rQ14 = (q.Q14 == true) ? "Yes" : "No",
                                    rQ15 = (q.Q15 == true) ? "Yes" : "No",
                                    rQ16 = (q.Q16 == true) ? "Yes" : "No",
                                    rQ17 = (q.Q17 == true) ? "Yes" : "No",
                                    rQ18 = (q.Q18 == true) ? "Yes" : "No",
                                    rQ19 = (q.Q19 == true) ? "Yes" : "No",
                                    rQ20 = (q.Q20 == true) ? "Yes" : "No",
                                    rQ21 = (q.Q21 == true) ? "Yes" : "No",
                                    rQ22 = (q.Q22 == true) ? "Yes" : "No",
                                    rQ23 = (q.Q23 == true) ? "Yes" : "No",
                                    rQ24 = (q.Q24 == true) ? "Yes" : "No",
                                    rQ25 = (q.Q25 == true) ? "Yes" : "No",
                                    rQ26 = (q.Q26 == true) ? "Yes" : "No",
                                    rQ27 = (q.Q27 == true) ? "Yes" : "No",
                                    rQ28 = (q.Q28 == true) ? "Yes" : "No",
                                    rQ29 = (q.Q29 == true) ? "Yes" : "No"
```

Comment: the real issue was converting a boolean to yes / no. this was the easiest way to do it

Answer (score 4):

This is a case where you should do some of the query processing on the client side.  IE Fetch the YesNos into a local dictionary and to the final select on the client.  Something like this:

```
var questrpt =  from f in db.FDS
                join q in db.Questions
                on f.FDS_Num equals q.FDS_Num
                where f.Filed_Year >= startyear
                && f.Filed_Year <= endyear
                orderby f.Filed_Year, f.FDS_Num
                select new {fds=f, question=q};

var yn = from y in db.YesNos
            select new (y.YN_Bit,y.YN_Value);

var ynByBit = yn.ToDictionary(y => y.YN_Bit, y => YN_Value);

var result = from q in questrpt.ToList()
                select new 
                (
                    fds.FDS_Num,
                    yearr = fds.Filled_Year,
                    rQ01 = ynByBit[q.Q1],
                    rQ02 = ynByBit[q.Q2],
                    rQ03 = ynByBit[q.Q3],
                    //. . .
                );
```

Comment: using the dictionary in the query is giving me the same problem where the grid view doesn't load. I'm thinking it should work but for some reason the grid view doesn't load with even one dictionary reference in the query. can you advise on why the using the dictionary in the query might cause the grid view to fail to load? your help is much appreciated! thanks!